# taskkill a batch file that kills a task

Tags: batch-file, cmd, putty

i got a process that gets stuck if it didnt find its target so i call a batch file to kill it after sometime

```
start C:\file\server\bin\killput.bat
C:\file\server\bin\putty.exe -ssh 192.168.0.210 -l oracle -pw oracle -m C:\file\server\bin\List_AIX.txt
```

the thing is how to kill the cmd running the kill command if my process gets executed

code for my killput.bat batch file

```
Timeout 20
taskkill /f /im putty.exe
```

Comment: So basically you want to check wheter putty runns correctly or not, right? And if you see that it got stuck you want to kill the batch-file that would otherwise kill the putty process? I would suggest: Run putty from the **commandline** as you do with your first batch-file now (-> just the lower line). If putty acts correctly and is done whatever it does, type `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` and hit [Enter]. If the value is different from 0 I think I can help. That would be my way though...

Answer (score 0):

I checked with my putty and if fails it won't maintain any connection so you just won't see it on "netstat" command output and if you don't find it in that output it means the connection has either failed or just completed. So I figured you could do something like that on your kill batch:

```
timeout 20

SET tempfl=c:\windows\temp\netstatresult.txt
netstat -aonb>%tempfl%

for /f "delims=" %i in ('findstr /i /C:putty %tempfl%') do SET output=%i
if NOT DEFINED %output% taskkill /f /im putty.exe

del %tempfl%
```

So this writes the output of **netstat** to a temp file, after that we check if the output of the commmand contains the substring putty using **findstr**.
If **findstr** had any results the variable **output** is set with value otherwise it won't be defined, so if there is a value it means that putty is running successfully and you don't have to kill it and if there isn't you can kill the putty process.

After that there is just a simple if that runs **taskkill** if the variable is not defined, and then the temp file created is deleted.

Just making sure if you dont know what netstat is used for:
https://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Start C:\file\server\bin\putty.exe -ssh 192.168.0.210 -l oracle -pw oracle -m C:\file\server\bin\List_AIX.txt
Timeout 20
Taskkill /IM PuTTY.exe
```